# Can I create a crontab "on the fly" in a script?

Tags: bash, cron

I have a script that creates some temporary files that need to remain in place for quite some time.  I want the user who executes the script to be able to create their own custom crontab that removes these files at a later time.

To test, I've just simply tried to setup a simple crontab using the command-line exclusively, but I'm not sure if this is even possible.

From the command-line I type the following:

```
$ crontab 1 * * * * $(mkdir -p ~/Desktop/CronSuccess)
```

I get the error: `crontab: 1: No such file or directory`

Is there anyway to have a script create a fully functional crontab on the fly?

Comment: Try using notify-send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the manpage for crontab

You can't do what you're trying to do. 
You can however have crontab read the entries from a file.
e.g.

```
echo 'crontab 1 * * * * mkdir -p ~/Desktop/CronSuccess' >mycrontab
crontab mycrontab
```

Be aware that this will not append to the users crontab, it will replace the existing crontab of the user
with what's in the `mycrontab` file.
Surrounding the mkdir command with $() would be wrong.

You might also use `at` if it suits your needs:
e.g.

```
echo 'mkdir -p ~/Desktop/CronSuccess' | at now + 10 hours
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  So even though it will not add it to the users crontab, how will the crontab run?  As root?

Comment: I reworded it. It will not append to the user crontab. It will overwrite it. Which could annoy some users.